# Ext JS 4: Multiple MVC Apps

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two different ext js mvc apps with two different package structure.

```
|---A
    |--- controller
    |---- model
    |---- store
    |---- view
|---B
    |--- controller
    |---- model
    |---- store
    |---- view
           |--pkgA.view.viewA
           |-- viewB 
a.js  // app.js for A
a.jsp
b.js  // app.js for B
b.jsp
```

B uses A. Therefore I defined and accessed in the b.js with full package name ( eg: pkgA.view.ViewA )

Everything works if I used ext-all-debug.js. But nothing loaded if I use ext-all.js. No error. very strange. As soon as I remove all A's refs in the app.js of B then ext-all.js works

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a Loader issue. Are you sure you're not getting any error? No 404 on js scripts in the network panel of your developer tool?

Comment: Nothing in the FB. I have Ext.Loader.setPath('Gtp.A', 'A'); at the top of b.js

Comment: And all your requires are in place? That is, when using ext-all-dev.js, you don't have any warning "Synchronously loading..."? From my test, ext-all.js doesn't disable that, but I know that the Loader's default have changed along Ext4 version, so who knows?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Ext JS "packages"](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html)? That should be almost exactly what you're asking for.